# Usar archivos para guardar consultas SQL es bueno para el rendimiento

Tags: sql, nodejs, archivo

Estoy realizando un proyecto nuevo en node.js, pero tengo la incógnita si es una buena idea guardar las consultas SQL en archivo para poder versionar en git, ya que estoy usando el orm squelize.

### [image: Ejemplo]

usando la librera fs de node.js, para recuperar la información y luego con una funcion para ejecutar la consulta sql.

> Esto seria bueno en un sotfware transaccional

Comment: Bienvenido para enteder mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]

Comment: te parece que es mejor leer un archivo para ejecutar la consulta que colocarla en tu .js?

Comment: si eso lo pense pero, toca ponerlo todo en una linea o concatenar el query para que se vea bien, no se de que manera se podria representar bien un query en un varible.

Comment: econtre esta pagina con lo que tu dices se puede minificar el query y poner en una sola linea https://www.beautifyconverter.com/sql-minifier.php